# Вывод ограниченное кол-во символов

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Как урезать можно выводимый текст до определённого кол-ва символов?
Вывожу через

```
for each
' . ( $post['text'] ). '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php

```
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Из документации: Возвращает подстроку строки string, начинающейся с start символа по счету и длиной length символов. 
В Вашем случае: $start - 0, $length - к-во символов, которое хотите вывести.